# How to getValue the data on setActivityForresult

Tags: android, android-intent

This is what i want to do. When a user starts the game, he is taken to a dashboard screen with several categories that he is suppossed to choose from. On clicking any of the categories one is lead to to the a single activity where i need to know how to find which category button was choosen in the ActivityB.
So, in the DashboardActivity, i have this code:

```
public void onGeneralKnowledgeClick(View v) {
    createIntent("GENERAL_KNOWLEDGE", 1);

}
    ........
    ........
    ........
public void onCelebritiesClick(View v) {
    createIntent("CELEBRITIES", 6);
}

private void createIntent(String category, int result) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(category, result);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            QuestionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Now, in my QuestionActivity class, i have a method that tries to get the categoryNumber associated with the intent that was started. So, i have something like this:

```
private int getCategory() {
   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
      int categ = bundle.getInt("GENERAL_KNOWLEDGE");
   return categ;

}
```

**My problem is that**, how do i return the integer category such and not hardcording as i did up here. I want this method to return a the integer from the respective bundle. my idea is to have a switch statement inside the getCategory but i don't know what case value to use. Also, i saw someone saying that onActivityResult can be used but i don't see how.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're a bit confused. You merely need to do:

```
bundle.putInt("CATEGORY", result); //where result == the categoryId and "CATEGORY" is always "CATEGORY"
```

Then in your `getCategory()`:

```
int categ = bundle.getInt("CATEGORY") //you'll get the int value that you fed before
```

Unless I misunderstood.

Comment: thanks dmon for the help, that worked for me. You were also right, i was a bit confused, i am now feeling better:D